# Can I use Google Cloud Endpoints just on a specific endpoint in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm working on an project on GAE which contains several high traffic endpoints and one endpoint that has low traffic but need authentication. My question is, can I enable Cloud Endpoints on the low traffic endpoint for authentication, but not on those high traffic endpoints, because Endpoints is expensive?

My understanding of how Cloud Endpoints work with GAE is that once the swagger file is deployed, and you specify a Endpoints version in app.yaml file, all traffic that goes through the Endpoints proxy server before reaching the application server. Also because Endpoints is charged based on # of requests, so in my case the entire application will take tens of millions request per day, but only a tiny fraction of that request will goes to a specific endpoint in the application that requires authentication.

In order to avoid spending thousands of dollars per month on Endpoint, It would be way cheaper if I can only let those privileged request go through Cloud Endpoints, and be charged only on those request.

Comment: Could elaborate a bit more on what you mean? How are the "high traffic endpoints" avoiding traffic/cost? What do you mean by "enable Cloud Endpoints on the low traffic endpoints for authentication but not on those high traffic endpoints"?

Do you expect some interaction between the authenticated Endpoints and the "non-authenticated" high traffic URLs (I am not calling them Endpoints to avoid confusion)?

Comment: My understanding of how Cloud Endpoints work with GAE is that once the swagger file is deployed, and you specify a Endpoints version in `app.yaml` file, all traffic that goes through the Endpoints proxy server before reaching the application server. Also because Endpoints is charged based on # of requests, so in my case the entire application will take tens of millions request per day, but only a tiny fraction of that request will goes to a specific endpoint in the application that requires authentication.

Comment: In order to avoid spending thousands of dollars per month on Endpoint, It would be way cheaper if I can only let those privileged request go through Cloud Endpoints, and be charged only on those request. Hope that would clarify my intention.

Comment: There is no proxy server in the App Engine standard environment, only the flex environment.

If you are using the standard environment, the "management framework" provides the proxy server features. Ultimately an Endpoints Framework app is a WSGI app, so it can be just part of your app if need be.

If you are using the flexible environment, things are normally set up so you can only access the app through the proxy server; this is for security reasons.

Please clarify which environment you're using.

Comment: I'm using flexible environment.

Comment: I see. So your question is basically a billing question? "If I only need Endpoints authenticate on one of my URLs and not the rest. If I deploy my app with Endpoint enabled, would all my requests be billed according to Endpoint pricing?"

How are you currently trying to set your URLs apart and not use Endpoints in your app.yaml? What did you do to differentiate the different URLs so Google would know which one doesn't need Endpoints?

Comment: Currently the way to enable Cloud Endpoints was to add `endpoints_api_service:
  name: "www.example.com"
  config_id: "2017-12-27r0"`
to the `app.ymal` file. I already figure out the billing part, as the bill for Endpoint has made its way to our monthly bills. 
I tried to remove all endpoints in the swagger file, but all request will go through Endpoints under `GET /**`. A better way to phrase my question would be "Is there a way to set up Endpoints in flexible environment so that only `www.example.com/previllage` is billed for using Endpoints, but rest of `www.example.com` will not?"

Comment: I understand what you mean now, I will add an answer. So only one needs to be Endpoints, the others URLs can be completely unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have only one Endpoint (thus only one charged Endpoint pricing), if you separate it from the other URLs. You can do that by [separating the Services or Projects](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine#app_engine_services_as_microservices)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any way to achieve the same thing by having both endpoint under the same service and same version?

Comment: If by "achieve the same thing", you mean bypassing the proxy server, once you have Endpoint configured on your service, then no... At least not in the public documented way. The [deployment configurations](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/deploy-redeploy-api]) doesn't have that option.

However, if you are looking for a feature request or ask question about how non-Endpoints URLs are billed, you will get more detailed response submitting a case with Google Cloud Platform Support.

Separate Project/Service is the best way to do it.